# Getting CairoSVG to recognise a local image in the URL

Tags: python

Using [cairosvg](http://cairosvg.org/) in python (on Windows) to convert some SVGs to PNGs and struggling with it a little, the line I'm stuck on is:

```
cairosvg.svg2png(url=r'C:\images\image.svg', write_to=r'C:\images\image.png')
```

The error seems to be suggesting that the URL is incorrect, but I'm not quite sure what to do with the information that it's giving me:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: c>
```

I'm guessing that this could be something to do with using a C drive location rather than a web URL, as it works fine with something like:

```
cairosvg.svg2png(url=r'http://www.images.com/image.svg', write_to=r'C:\images\image.png')
```

I'm not sure how to do anything differently when I have locally stored images?

Comment: I would try with a `file://` local URL, such as `file://c:/images/image.png`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading at the [documentation](http://cairosvg.org/documentation/), it looks like you can read a local file using a file object. Maybe try something like this:

```
cairosvg.svg2png(file_obj=open(r'C:\images\image.svg', "rb"), write_to=r'C:\images\image.png')
```